# WalletConnect integration in angular

Tags: angular, wallet-connect

**I get wallet address in metamask but I need to get signed signature from user wallet.**

**this is my service file**

```
accounts:any  
async connectWalletConnect() {

this.walletconnectProvider = new WalletConnectProvider({
  infuraId: "27e484dcd9e3efcfd25a83a78777cdf1",


  rpc:{
    1:'https://cloudflare-eth.com/',
    137:'https://polygon-rpc.com'
  }
});

this.walletconnectProvider.enable();

this.web3 = new Web3(this.walletconnectProvider)
window.w3 = this.web3

this.accounts = await this.web3.eth.getAccounts(); // get all connected accounts
this.accounts 

console.log(this.accounts[0])
this.sign()

}

async sign(){
 try {
  
   await this.web3.eth.personal.sign('hello world', this.accounts)

 } catch (error) {
   console.log('faild', error)
 }
}
```

Comment: If you got any solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

below code snippet can be used for wallet connect integration using ethersjs

```
accounts:any  
signer:any

async connectWalletConnect() {
this.walletconnectProvider = new WalletConnectProvider({
  infuraId: "27e484dcd9e3efcfd25a83a78777cdf1",
  rpc:{
    1:'https://cloudflare-eth.com/',
    137:'https://polygon-rpc.com'
  }
});

await this.walletconnectProvider.enable();

this.web3 = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(this.walletconnectProvider)
window.w3 = this.web3

this.accounts = await this.web3.eth.getAccounts(); 
this.signer = this.web3.getSigner();
console.log(this.accounts[0])
this.sign()

}

async sign(){
 try {
   const signedMessage = await this.signer.signMessage('hello world');
   console.log("signed message", signedMessage);
 } catch (error) {
   console.log('failed', error)
 }
}
```